# My label keeps on getting into my django form field, how do I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx4ez.png)
I have been following up on a django tutorial based around building an e-commerce site. I am currently working on the checkout page for the e-commerce website; I am making use of django forms but the label I attach to my form field keeps getting into the field and when you type into form field it creates this murky text that is very unpleasant. I can't just fix it and it is driving mad, please can someone help me check it out ? Sorry if my presentation is a bit off, I am not used to stackoverflow.

```html
checkout.html
 
 <div class="md-form mb-5">
                  {{ form.street_address }}
                   <label  for= "address" class =""><b>Address</b></label>

<!--                  <label for="address" class="">Address</label>-->
              </div>

              <!--address-2-->
              <div class="md-form mb-5">
<!--              <input type="text" id="address-2" class="form-control" placeholder="Apartment or suite">-->
                  {{ form.apartment_address }}
                  <label  for = "address2" class =''><b>Address 2</b></la
```

```
     from django import forms
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django_countries.widgets import CountrySelectWidget

PAYMENT_OPTIONS = (
    ('S', 'Stripe'),
    ('P', 'PayPal'),
)


class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    street_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': '1234 main st.',
        'class': 'form-control',
        'id': 'address',
        'name': 'address'
    }
    ))
    apartment_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Apartment or Suite',
        'class': 'form-control',
        'id': 'address2',
        'name': 'address2'
    }
    ), required=False)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)').formfield(widget=CountrySelectWidget(attrs= {
        'class': 'custom-select d-block w-100'
    }))
    zip = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control'
    }))
    same_billing_address = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
    save_info = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
    payment_option = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=PAYMENT_OPTIONS)
```

Comment: Can you post a picture or better description of what the problem is?

Comment: @Josh I have added a link above it above.

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping text here. Remove either

```
<label  for= "address" class =""><b>Address</b></label>
```

or

```
placeholder': '1234 main st.'
```

and it should look better.